# What is wrong with my code on printing a random image in a website?

Tags: php, arrays, image, syntax-error

this is the code in order to display a random image on my website,
    but for some reason the images are not popping up and there is an error on the line where $rand_image was declared. The error says undefined index. I have 7 images in the directory.

```
$imagesDir = '\socimages\Badminton'; // my image directory
$images = glob($imagesDir . '*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE); // glob
$rand_image = $images[array_rand($images)]; // applying the random function
...
...
<img src="<?php echo $rand_image[0];?>"< alt="" height="246" width="246"></p></div>
```

Comment: Is glob returning an array or FALSE? You should test that.

Comment: just <?php echo $rand_image;?>

Answer (score 2):

`$rand_image` is the image already you don't need `$rand_image[0]`;

```
<img src="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($rand_image);?>"< alt="" height="246" width="246"></p></div>
```

Also, `$rand_image` will probably be the path on disk, not the web accessible path so you'll need to map it.

Answer (score 2):

I'd do something like this.

```
$imagesDir = '/socimages/Badminton/'; // my image directory
$images = glob($imagesDir . '*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE); // glob
if ($images !== FALSE) {
   $rand_image = $images[array_rand($images)]; // applying the random function
} else {
   die("This thang ain't working, yo.");
}
...
...
<img src="<?php echo $rand_image;?>"< alt="" height="246" width="246"></p></div>
```

Comment: `$imagesDir = '/socimages/Badminton/';` that risks in failing, as using a leading slash for folders requires a full system path. I.e.: `$imagesDir = '/var/user/html/socimages/Badminton/';` - Otherwise, OP must use `$imagesDir = 'socimages/Badminton/';` if executed from the root.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yeah I don't know how the user's directories are setup, it seems like they should be able to figure that part out on their own. I wouldn't do anything like this poster is doing, but ...

Comment: OP has enough to go on in your answer and comments to figure it out ;-)